# Arba'a Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first day of Pesach up to and including Hoshana Rabah is exactly 184 days.

Answer (score 1):

> In this period, the authorities
>   supported Soviet Yiddish culture. In
>   1927, 24,100 Jewish pupils were
>   enrolled in **184** Yiddish-language
>   schools; in 1933, some 36,500 were
>   enrolled in 339 schools.

http://www.yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Belarus